What is the process for calculating bending moments in beams for a bridge structure?
Follow-up: How do variable loads (e.g., traffic) affect these calculations?



Identify beam type and support conditions (e.g., simply supported,
cantilever).   Determine loading conditions (e.g., dead load, live
load, impact load).

Calculate support reactions using static equilibrium (sum of forces
and moments).

Draw the Shear Force Diagram(SFD) to show how shear forces vary
across the beam.

Draw the Bending Moment Diagram (BMD) by integrating shear forces.

Compare the maximum bending moment with the beam’s material strength
to ensure safety.


For complex structures, software like FEA might be required.
